# How to save a pickle file in python in a physical folder

Tags: python, pickle

I am new to using pickle in python.

This is how I dump data in a pickle file

```
result = "123"
pickle.dump(result, open("result.p","wb"))
```

I am able to read this file using

```
pickle.load(open("result.p", "rb"))
```

Now what I am not able to see is the physical pickle file result.p after I dump data in to it. 
My question is: where does this pickle file get stored after serialized data is dumped in to it.

Comment: works for me on Python 2.7 and 3.6.  Please show the full error backtrace.

Comment: just look what `os.path.abspath("result.p")` returns.

Comment: @user69453 That should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one of the two things:

1) Find out what is the working directory for your program / Python interpreter session. This is where this file is created.

One of the ways to do it (from the Python interpreter):

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

2) Provide full path to the "open" function instead of only the filename part, in which case it would create the file where you specify it to be created.

Comment: Thanks. path = os.getswd + "\\" pickle.dump (path + "filename.p", "wb") did actually save the file physically.